# Replace characters in a field on page load

Tags: jquery

I need to remove the unwanted characters from a field. my current results inside the field are `<DT></DT><DD>57 MINUTES</DD>`

i try this but is not working

```js
jQuery('display').val(function(index, val){
    return val.replace('<DT></DT><DD>', '').trim();
});
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="display" value="<DT></DT><DD>0 MINUTES</DD>">
```

the wanted result its only the minutes.

Comment: Selector for id with jquery is '#_id'. so it should be '#display'

Answer (score 4):

```
$($('#display').val()).text()
```

`$($('#display').val())` This will convert your value into html.

`.text()` will retrieve the minutes field.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, use regular expression

and one small issue, you have missed selector `#`

```js
$('#display').val($('#display').val().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,""))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="display" value="<DT></DT><DD>0 MINUTES</DD>">
```